# Bound on the condition number of a PSD matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, condition-number

Suppose $x_s$ is a $d$ dimensional vector which are features in the regression model. Values in the vector $x_s$ are controlled or uncontrolled. For example, the first element might be chosen by a person, so it is not randomly selected.   We define $\mathbf{V}=\sum_{s=1}^{t}\mathbf{x}_s \mathbf{x}_s^\top + \lambda \mathbf{I}$ (design matrix in regression) where $\lambda$ is a positive scalar. Assuming that $l \le \| \mathbf{x}_s\| \le L$, how is it possible to find an upper bound on the condition number of the matrix $\mathbf{V}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\sum_sx_sx_s^T$ is positive semidefinite, the minimum possible eigenvalue of $V$ is $\lambda$. Also, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\lambda_\max(V)
&=\lambda+\lambda_\max(\sum x_sx_s^T)\\
&\le\lambda+\|\sum_sx_sx_s^T\|_F\\
&\le\lambda+\sum_s\|x_sx_s^T\|_F\\
&=\lambda+\sum_s\|x_s\|^2\\
&\le\lambda+tL^2.
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore the condition number of $V$ with respect to the induced $2$-norm, namely $\kappa(V)=\frac{\lambda_\max(V)}{\lambda_\min(V)}$, is bounded above by $\frac{\lambda+tL^2}{\lambda}$. This upper bound is sharp  if $d>1$. It is attained when all $x_s$s are the same vector with norm $L$.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: Is it possible to find an upper bound independent of $t$?

Comment: @Amin No, because the current bound is attainable.